# Selenium cannot find_element button by text if the said button also contains e.g. icon next to the text

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to select a button by text that looks like this:

```
<button>
  <svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"></path>
  </svg> 

  The button
</button>
```

I am trying to utilize the `find_element` API:

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[text()="The button"]')
```

I believe it is because of the `svg` element in there, but I am not sure.

I would like to be able to make assertions like this without the need for unique selectors (id or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly parent element text content contains the text content of it child elements.
Also looks like the `button` element itself text content contains white spaces in addition to `The button` text here.
So, instead of `browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[text()="The button"]')` please try this:

```py
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[contains(.,"The button")]')
```

You can also try locating that element by removing the trailing and leading spaces with the use of `normalize-space()` as following:

```py
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[normalize-space()="The button"]')
```